# WordPress - Custom plugin for maintenance mode not work

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, maintenance-mode

I have created a simple plugin to activate maintenance mode in wp with this code

```php
class Maintenance {
  
  public function __construct()
  {
     add_action('get_header', [$this, 'enable_maintenance_mode']);
  }

  public function enable_maintenance_mode()
  {
     if(!current_user_can('edit_themes') || !is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_die('Website under maintenance');
     }
  }

}

new Maintenance();
```

Anyway the website is loaded and the maintenance mode isn't enabled. I've also tried to add the function into the deafult wordpress theme but not work. Is there any way to fix it without installing third party plugins?

Comment: Maybe consider using a [`.maintenance` file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/254771/12496) along with the [`enable_maintenance_mode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enable_maintenance_mode/) filter if you want to allow admins into the site still. The [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/9805a98734c673a7f493aeb35bc290174a44788f/wp-includes/load.php#L303) shows how this is used.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've added the maintenance file, but I'm unable to login, and I've noticed that the `wp_die()` custom message will be not show. I need to go deeper about

Comment: @ChrisHaas do I need to call also the filter and create a `maintenance.php` file?

Comment: The core WordPress maintenance logic blocks everyone from doing everything, including logging in. If you want to safelist the login page through [see this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12865/12496). For the process, your code (or FTP) would create the `.maintenance` file with the noted contents which will block everyone. You'd then use the `enable_maintenance_mode` filter to allow certain people to bypass the block. Note, not all core functions might be available because it is pretty early in the process.

Comment: @ChrisHaas ok. I've also found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169600/redirect-visitors-to-a-temporary-maintenance-page/169610#169610) and I will take a look to it. If you leave an answer I will mark it as accepted. Thank you for the help

Comment: If you want to post what you ultimately got to work as an answer I'd be fine with that

Comment: @newbiedev You have typo in `__contruct`. It should be `__construct `.

Comment: @NilambarSharma it's a typo on the thread, not in the class code. I fix it